# GROUP BY in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

Assume that I uses the FOAF ontology. I want to return the `name` and the `mbox` for each person. I use the following query:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?email
WHERE {
  ?person foaf:name ?name.
  ?person foaf:mbox ?email.
}
```

The result of the join is a set of rows: `?person`, `?name`, `?email`. This query is returning the `?name` and `?email`. Note that in some of the `?person` may have multiple mailboxes, so in the returned set, a `?name` row may appear multiple times, once for each mailbox.

Is there a solution to make a `GROUP BY person ?name`?

Answer (score 2):

You can group by person but then you need an aggregation for `?name` and `?email`

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT (sample(?name) AS ?name2) (sample(?email) as ?email2)
WHERE {
  ?person foaf:name ?name.
  ?person foaf:mbox ?email.
} GROUP BY ?person
```

`SAMPLE` picks one possible from the group for each `?person`.

or maybe

```
SELECT (group_concat(?name) AS ?names)
```

(except that's a string).

It may be easier work with

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?name ?email
WHERE {
  ?person foaf:name ?name.
  ?person foaf:mbox ?email.
} 
ORDER BY ?person ?name ?email
```

and process the results in your application where you know the incoming results have all the entries for one person is a single section of the results.